# How to retrieve course that has the cut off point from the SQL Server database that the user type in using luis intent

Tags: c#, sql-server, botframework

I want to retrieve all courses that has the cut off point that the user type in from the SQL Server database. what should i change to the activity in var text = activity.text; because if i add Activity activity in the luis intent method there will be error when i run the emulator. Is there any other method to replace the activity.

I got the code from http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/13/Implementing-A-SQL-Server-Database-With-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework and have change the code according to my requirement. Thank You.

```
     [LuisIntent("CutOffPoint")]
    public async Task CutOffPoint(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        Models.BotDataEntities2 DB = new Models.BotDataEntities2();



        // Get the top 5 high scores since yesterday


        var text = activity.text;


        if (!Int32.TryParse(text, out int number))
        {
            //reply that there is no number;


            return;

        }

        // Get the top 5 high scores since yesterday
        var Courses = (from UserLog in DB.NYPCourses
                       where (UserLog.Course != null) && (UserLog.CutOffPoint == number)
                       select UserLog)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Course)
            .ToList();

        // Create a response

        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("Course Information:\n\n");

        // Loop through each high score
        foreach (var Course in Courses)
        {
            // Add the High Score to the response
            sb.Append(String.Format("School: {0}/ Course: {1}/ Course Code: {2}/ Cut Off Point: {3})\n\n"
                , Course.School
                , Course.Course
                , Course.CourseCode
                , Course.CutOffPoint));
        }



        await context.PostAsync(sb.ToString());
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use logical operators in your linq condition:

```
int number = -1;
foreach(var entity in result.Entities)
{
    if(entity.Type == "builtin.number")
    {
        number = Convert.ToInt32(entity.Resolution["value"]);
    }
}
if (number == -1)
    // reply that there is no number;
    return;
}

var HighScores = (from UserLog in DB.NYPCourses
    where (UserLog.Course != null) && (UserLog.CutOffPoint == number)
    select UserLog)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Course)
    .ToList();
```

Make sure to activate the builtin luis entity "number" before trying this.

Comment: i want the user to type in 19 cut off point into the bot emulator and all course that has the 19 cut off point will show up. do you know how to do it another way that is not hard coding

Comment: for some reason the AsMessageActivity() is being highlight as a error. The error said the activity does not contain a definition for "AsMessageActivity" and no extension method "AsMessageActivity". I have call the using Microsoft.Bot.Connector but it is still not working. Sorry for the trouble. Thank you

Comment: I have looked at the link again and noticed that the method is defined in the controller. This means you are able to use activity.Text. I'll update my answer.

Comment: can i have the code for the AsMessageActivity() method of doing because i am connecting the data from sql database to luis intent and in the luis intent method i add IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> message. Thank you

Comment: If your going to use LUIS then you're working in with Luisresults and not with IMessageActivities. check [this example](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dialogs.html#alarmBot) in the documentation.

Comment: can you change the answer to not include activity inside the code because in the luis intent method cannot contain Activity activity as the utterance will not work if you contain it inside when retrieve the data from sql database. Do you have any method that is different that do not require activity and can retrieve the number from database. Thank you

Comment: I don't see how you can do this without an Activity or LuisResult unless you want to hardcode your cut-off point.

Comment: i have update my code above. can you take a look at it. Thank you.